# How to use Jenkins to push to Github on test success?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I currently have a Python project on Git. The repo has 2 different remotes; one called `origin` and another called `github`. There is a Jenkins job that triggers when a commit is made to `origin/master` and it runs unittests with the command `nosetests-3.2 -v`. When the tests finish successfully, I want the Jenkins job to push to `github/master`. I tried using the GitPublisher post-build action, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher aborted due to exception
hudson.AbortException: No repository found for target repo name github
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher.perform(GitPublisher.java:330)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
```

What am I doing wrong? This is what my GitPublisher config looks like:

[image: GitPublisher Config]

Comment: Remotes are not synced when you do a git push. Are you sure that the git repo that Jenkins is using has the `github` remote?

Comment: This is the problem and thank you for the insight. The local copy on my local machine has the 2 remotes. The clone of the `origin/master` made by Jenkins has only one remote called `origin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment copy/pasted into an answer so that it can be accepted:

> Remotes are not synced when you do a git push. Are you sure that the git repo that Jenkins is using has the `github` remote?

Comment: Is there a way to sync all remotes on a push?

Comment: No, but you should be able to use the github ssh url as the origin name.